# Auto select multiple dropdown with formBuilder

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I've created a multiple select dropdown but in that list I would like to make auto select.

for example:

```
String[] names = ["ant", "bat", "cat", "dog"];
String[] autoSelectName = ["bat", "dog"];
```

So what I exactly want that I would like to bat and dog should be selected when I'll open the dropdown.

.html

```
<mat-form-field id="name-dropdown">
    <mat-select formControlName="names" multiple>
         <mat-option *ngFor="let name of names" [value]="name">
             {{name}}
         </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need "feed" with an array the formControl, e.g.

using pathValue:

```
this.form.pathValue({names:this.autoSelectName})
```

using setValue to the control:

```
this.form.get('names').setValue(this.autoselectName)
```

When you create the form using the contructors:

```
 this.form=new FormGroup({
     names:new FormControl(this.autoSelectName,Validators.required)
 })
```

Using formBuilder

```
 this.form=this.fb.group({
    names:[this.autoSelectName,Validators.required]
 })
```

Even you neen't an auxiliar variable

```
 this.form=this.fb.group({
    names:[["bat", "dog"],Validators.required]
 })
```